# Prove that every nonempty finite set has a maximum.

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

how do I prove that every nonempty finite set has a maximum. I know how to explain this by words but didn't know how to put it into mathematical form. I found a way to prove this by induction in MathExchange but it was so complicated.

Comment: Induction seems the natural way to me. I suspect alternatives are likely to be more complicated.

Comment: Maybe someone can use induction in a more easy to understand way to clear this.

Comment: The statement to prove is $\forall n\in \mathbb N(P(n))$. where $P(n)$ abbreviates $\forall A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\setminus \{\varnothing\}(|A|=n\implies \text{ $A$ has a maximum})$. You need to prove $P(1)$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb N(P(n)\implies P(n+1))$. Can you do anything?

Comment: If you have two elements, then the conclusion is equivalent to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered. Assume that your set has $n$ elements, and that the theorem has been proved for sets with $k \leq n$ elements. Then pick any point and consider its complement. Now you have a largest element in the complement, and you compare with the point you picked up before.

Comment: I'm joking so I won't call this an answer, but under the assumption that you are asking about a finite set with a total order and you just want a quicker proof than induction, you could always use Zorn's lemma :)

Comment: Apply your favorite sorting algorithm to your set.  If you accept the correctness of the sorting algorithm, then the largest element of the sorted set is the maximum element.  [You could also do this with a partial sort--such as one pass of a right-to-left bubble sort.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof by contradiction.

Pick $x_1$. If the last picked element is $x_i$, then either $x_i$ is a maximum or you can pick $x_{i+1}\gt x_i$. If the process terminates you have found a maximum.

Suppose there are $n$ elements in the set, and the process does not terminate. $\{x_1, \dots x_{n+1}\}$ must have two equal elements. Since the elements are distinct (because of the order), this is impossible. Hence the process terminates with a maximum.

This uses the pigeonhole principle - a fact about maps between finite sets.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a statement about order.

You have some finite set $S$ and a total order $\le$ (that is, for any $x,y \in S$, either $x \le y $ or
$y \le x$).

Given a non-empty finite set $S$, we say that $m$ is a maximum of $S$ **iff** $m \in S$ and for all $x \in S$, we have $x \le m$.

Induction is straightforward. Suppose $S$ is a non-empty, finite set.

The proposition is that for all sets of size $|S| \le n$ that a maximum of $S$ exists.

For $n=1$, just choose the element of the set.

Suppose the statement is true for $n$, and let $S$ be a set with $|S| = n+1$. Choose $x \in S$ and form $S' = S \setminus \{x\}$. By assumption, $S'$ has a maximum $m'$. If $x \le m'$, then let $m=m'$, otherwise if $m' \le x$ and $m' \neq x$, let $m = x$. Then we have $m \in S$ and $x \le m$ for all $x \in S$, hence
$m$ is a maximum of $S$.

Comment: what does S′=S∖{x} means by words?

Comment: The set $S'$ is the set $S$ with the element $x$ removed.